# Javascript getElementById from parent window to child window

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, parent, getelementbyid

Hello and thank you for reading my post.

Here is what I basically want to do:

- in a first HTML page ("parent.html"), there is a button ;
- when a user clicks the button a new window pops up ("child.html")
- AND the contents of a "div" element in the child window is updated.

The final action is unsuccessful under "Firefox" and "Chrome".

**parent.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Parent window document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input 
     type="button" 
     value="Open child window document" 
     onclick="openChildWindow()" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function openChildWindow()
    {
      var s_url     = "http://localhost:8080/projectroot/child.html";
      var s_name    = "ChildWindowDocument";
      var s_specs   = "resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=0,status=0";
      var childWnd  = window.open(s_url, s_name, s_specs);
      var div       = childWnd.document.getElementById("child_wnd_doc_div_id");
      div.innerHTML = "Hello from parent wnd";
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**child.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Parent window document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="child_wnd_doc_div_id">child window</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

- IE9 => it works.
- Firefox 13.0.1 => it doesn't work. Error message: "div is null".
- Chrome 20.0.1132.47 m => doesn't work.

Do you understand that behaviour?

Can you help me make it work in these three cases?

Thank you and best regards.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the window/document is not loaded at the time when you try to access the elements from it. You can do something like

```
childWnd.onload = function() {
    var div       = childWnd.document.getElementById("child_wnd_doc_div_id");
    div.innerHTML = "Hello from parent wnd";
}
```

Also you can take a look at the [mdn doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Working_with_windows_in_chrome_code#section_4).

---

A better approach to the problem may be to do the changes in the 'child'. You can access the parent window with `window.opener`. But you should keep in mind that the parent window could be closed so you should consider some type of local storage (e.g. cookie).

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer.
This indeed solves the problem for "Firefox" and "Chrome" but it's not working with "IE" anymore...
Best regards.

Comment: It seems that window.open returns before the window is created in IE. Here is a possible solution http://flightschool.acylt.com/devnotes/window-open-onload-window-events/ but I will try to find/make a better one (tomorrow maybe...).

Comment: Hello again and thank you for your answer.

I followed the link you pointed me to (the one with the "timeout" trick (http://flightschool.acylt.com/devnotes/window-open-onload-window-events/)) and I customized my code in such a way it now indeed works in the three browsers mentionned in my first post.
Yet it's not fully satisfactory (that "timeout" trick)... so I would - of course - be interested in a "better" solution.

[Follow in next comment]

Comment: I also have been thinking that maybe I should get what I need in the child window from the parent window because I know that the parent DOM actually exists when the child window is opened...

I don't know if I make myself clear here...

Thank you for helping and sharing your thoughts with me.